# "make" command not working

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc, programming, g++

I'm currently trying to install graphics.h to do C programming, but I've been having a problem that I've been unable to solve so far.

Every tutorial explaining the process is the exact same, and they all have a step where you enter the extracted libgraph file, open the terminal and do:

```
./configure 
sudo make 
sudo make install 
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
```

I believe that all the steps before were done correctly (but I can try to describe them in more detail if it helps), but when using the "make" command I get an error:

```
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=link gcc -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DFONTDIR=\""/usr/local/share/libgraph/Font/"\" -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT   -o libgraph.la -rpath /usr/local/lib -version-info 1:2:0 -export-dynamic libgraph.lo text.lo shapes.lo polygon.lo  -lm -lSDL_image -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL 
gcc -shared  .libs/libgraph.o .libs/text.o .libs/shapes.o .libs/polygon.o  -lm -lSDL_image -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgraph.so.1 -o .libs/libgraph.so.1.0.2
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/text.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `InternalFont'; .libs/libgraph.o:(.bss+0x40): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/text.o:(.bss+0x810): multiple definition of `TP'; .libs/libgraph.o:(.bss+0x850): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/shapes.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_last_arc'; .libs/libgraph.o:(.bss+0x860): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/shapes.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `_internal_linestyle'; .libs/libgraph.o:(.bss+0x878): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/polygon.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_scanlist'; .libs/libgraph.o:(.bss+0x888): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:377: libgraph.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:552: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nazrin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
make: *** [Makefile:268: all] Error 2
```

I've tried were removing the "sudo", assuming the problem didn't matter and proceeding anyways, and redoing the tutorials all over again (I know that this doesn't seem like a lot, but as a starter in Linux, it's been a nightmare).
While I have found solutions for problems similar to mine, they didn't work either because my problem was totally different or because I was too dumb and did something wrong.

Comment: The `sudo` isn't related to the problem, but NEVER run `sudo make`! The `make` command compiles source code into an executable and does not require root access. Never run things with `sudo` unless you need to run them with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you did wrong is to try to get 20 yr. old code to compile/link with modern compilers/linkers.  This is not really a project for a beginner, but there are three ways to "fix" the problem.

1. Figure out a more modern approach/code for accomplishing what you are trying to do.
2. Look at the errors, and fix them.  The linker is telling you that certain things are being defined twice, like _last_arc.  Probably one of those should have been declared with an "extern" keyword to avoid the double allocation of space, causing the linker to barf.
3. There very well may be a linker option to overlay such double declarations, so change the makefile to add this option.

In any case, debugging 20 year old code is one way to learn to program, but not the way I would suggest.  Hint, the compiler produced the .o files, use nm to list the symbols, and see where the doublely declared items are found if you want to try the extern approach.

Comment: ... for point (3), see this related answer [Installing specific version of R pgmm library fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339615/installing-specific-version-of-r-pgmm-library-fails/1339739#1339739) and/or [Porting to GCC 10: C language issues - Default to -fno-common](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly? I'm not trying to compile C code, I'm trying to install a library (graphics.h in this case). If there's a misunderstanding on my side I'm very sorry, and if you're willing to spend some of your time on this I'd be thankful.

Comment: See 1143773, seems to be pretty much the same issue.  You didn't indicate which Ubuntu release you are using, or what exactly you are trying to do, but any graphics programming should have a ready made library from the standard repositories, not source you have to  compile.  The packages ending in "-dev" usually include both the library and any necessary include files. Maybe the forum is a better match to help you get started.

Comment: My Ubuntu release is 22.04
I've been looking for over two days now on how to do C graphics programming in Ubuntu, and I haven't seen any ready made library from the either from the standard repos or from anywhere else being mentioned.
I'll follow your tip of checking the forums out to see if I find anything I could use to solve my problem, and if you know some easy way to install a ready made graphics lib from the standard repos, please, tell me or refer me to a guide on how to install it.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/ ... gtk and qt are more logical libraries. But there are many more. Pygame is an easy tutorial friendly option, but unity3d, opengl, flutter may also be options depending what you want to achieve